# Comparing solutions of different equations

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

**Edit:** I have two equations.
\begin{equation}
f'(x_1)-g'(x_1)=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
k f'(x_2)-g'(x_2)=0
\end{equation}
I know additionally that $f,g$ are twice continuously differentiable functions such that: $f'<0,g'<0,f''<0,g''>0$. Do I know something (even adding additional assumptions) about the following relationship:
\begin{equation}
x_1 \gtreqless \frac{1}{k} x_2
\end{equation}

For instance, if $f',g'$ were linear ($f'''=g'''=0$), then $x_1=\frac{1}{k}x_2$.

I appreciate any help and apologize in advance if this may be somehow meaningless.

Comment: If $f'<0$ and $g'>0$, there is no $x_1$ such that $f'(x_1)=g'(x_1)$.

Comment: @Gonçalo sorry for the typo! We know that $g'<0$ also. I just edited the post. We also know that $f-g$ is concave. Then, $f''<0, g''>0$.

Comment: @Gonçalo, I have the intuition that $f'''<0,g'''>0 \Rightarrow (f-g)'''<0$ is sufficient to obtain $x_2<\frac{1}{k}x_1$. Am I right?